# Android LocationManager not throttling as expected

Tags: android

I am experiencing difficulties reliably throttling the gps update rate on the fly.  The following approach seems consistent with everything I read, and it will occasionally change the update rate once or twice (to, say, taking one GPS reading every four seconds) but after that it just stays at a rate and will no longer change.

```
    private LocationManager _locationMgr;
private LocationListener _locationListener;
private int _secondsPerUpdate=-1;

// Constructor
public AshGps(Activity l_activity, int l_secondsPerUpdate)
{
    _locationMgr = (LocationManager) l_activity.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    _locationListener = new mylocationlistener();
    _locationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, l_secondsPerUpdate*1000, 0, _locationListener);
    _secondsPerUpdate = l_secondsPerUpdate;
}


// Called up to once every three seconds
// to change the update rate
void ChangeUpdateRate(int l_secondsPerUpdate )
{
    if( _secondsPerUpdate != l_secondsPerUpdate )
    {
        _locationMgr.removeUpdates(_locationListener);
        _locationMgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, l_secondsPerUpdate*1000, 0, _locationListener);
        _secondsPerUpdate = l_secondsPerUpdate;
    }
}

// Methods handles the incoming GPS reading 'event' 
private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener 
{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The time period per update is a suggestion to Android. It will not always be honored. Quoting the documentation:

> This field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value.